# undelete answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

In short what am asking is when a moderator deletes a post.

1. The deleted post either can be undeleted by user
2. The moderator
   has choice to permanently delete the post or delete the post but the post still can be
   undeleted by user

Well as we know, over time things change, right? As I understand,  we cannot undelete a question if a moderator deleted it.

So, if the  cause for deleting a post is not severe there's no need to permanently delete it, since when you delete a post you are not actually deleting it, you are just hiding it. I see this as a waste of space if this space can be modified (later) to add new answer if the correct answer changed by time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask with this question... deleted posts can be undeleted though if you have the URL to access them by anybody with 10k rep or more

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here; if you didn't know, even if an post of yours was deleted because it wasn't an answer you can post a new answer which fixes whatever problem caused your first answer to be deleted.

Comment: It seems to me that you may be conflating question *closure* and question *deletion*. And even with that, I still have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: when moderator delete your post you cannot undelete it because moderator did that what am asking is to change that

Comment: If your answer has been deleted, perhaps you should be asking WHY it was deleted, not assuming it was deleted out of hand.  And if a moderator has deleted your answer, be assured they have good reasons to do so.  You're going to need to provide an example of where this happened if you really want to move this forward.

Comment: am speaking about reclaiming unused space if needed

Comment: @fido9dido which question?

Comment: @kalina it was my post  [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/do-you-still-gain-weapon-type-xp-when-the-weapons-xp-is-maxxed/119591#119591) . there was an update so i wanted to change answer but i couldn't undelete it i posted another answer but i saw it a waste of space

Comment: The correct course of action in that case is to edit your answer, and flag for attention.  If it was originally deleted, there's a good reason behind doing so, such as it not actually answering the question.

Comment: ik but this isn't what i meant. if the reason for deletion wasnt something sever let us modify answer and undelete it instead of posting new one. i didnt know about what Mad scientist said below tho

Comment: @fido9dido You can *already* modify your own deleted answers instead of posting a new one. Then, when you've edited your answer enough that it no longer deserved to be deleted, a moderator (or non-moderators with undelete voting powers) can undelete it. You're asking for a feature we *already have*.

Comment: Keep in mind that while *you* can see your old deleted answer, **nobody else can**. (Well, except for moderators and extremely high-rep users).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just flag for moderator attention and ask for undeletion when you fixed the post and a moderator will undelete it. It used to be that users could just undelete posts deleted by a mod, but this got rather annoying when some users just undeleted their posts without fixing anthying.

Comment: you cannot if moderator deleted your post that's why i'm suggesting that

Comment: *What* are you suggesting?

Comment: @fido9dido You can't undelete yourself, but you can flag for moderator attention

Comment: @mad scientist hmm i see

Answer (score 4):

As others pointed out, just fix the post and flag for moderator attention to get it undeleted, if it's really fixed it will be.

Now that you already posted another answer, there's no need though.
Don't worry about "wasted space".

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios here:

#### Scenario 1: Very bad answer gets deleted

Here we assume that the user was attempting to answer the question, but it was bad enough to get deleted.  ***That's normally pretty bad.***  The assumption when an answer gets deleted is that it is not salvageable by editing.  I would assume this is normally most often the case when the answer is so short as to be unintelligible.  Like others have mentioned, one approach here would be to edit the answer and flag for moderator attention.  I'd propose though that it would be as good or better to just submit a new answer as it requires no moderator intervention, and saves their attention for other things.

#### Scenario 2: Non-answer gets deleted

In this case, what was originally provided never attempted to answer the question.  It may have been spam, or more often a comment submitted in the answer field.  I believe this was the case with [your original answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/117478/revisions).  In such cases, it ***doesn't make sense to resurrect the old answer.***  It was never an answer to the question.  Any votes or revision history contained in it are irrelevant.  If you previously provided a non-answer and it gets deleted, its ok to let it go and **start fresh with a new answer**, which you have already done in this case.  Since you now understand the rules about where to comment, presumably this will be the only occurrence of this issue for you.

As a side note, my recollection is that reputation loss is refunded for downvoted answers that get deleted.  That would be another fringe benefit to starting fresh, if previously provided an non-answer and later wanted to add a real answer.